# How to REGEX match and doesn't match substring

Tags: javascript, php, regex, match

How to combine regex if match and doesn't match substring?

Ex:

```
http://www.domain.com/user.php?query=blah
http://www.domain.com/member.php?query=blah
http://www.domain.com/user.php?query=blah&context=DkUdh8ShTkNNkwoIJkl
http://www.domain.com/member.php?query=blah&context=DkUdDh8ShTaDfkNNkwoIJkl
```

I want to get url which contain `"user.php"` and `"member.php"` BUT I don't want to get url if contain `"context"`

To match url if contain "user.php" and "member.php" I can use:

```
(user\.php|user\.php)
```

And if doesn't contain "context":

```
^((?!context).)*$
```

How to combine `(user\.php|user\.php)` and `^((?!context).)*$` ?

My results should be:

```
http://www.domain.com/user.php?query=blah
http://www.domain.com/member.php?query=blah
```

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this pattern
<strike>`^(?=.*(?:user|member))(?!.*context).*$`</strike>
make it:

```
^(?=.*\/(?:user|member)\b\.php)(?!.*context).*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/86)

```
^                           # begining of string
(?=.*\/(?:user|member)\.php)        # look ahead for "/user.php" or "/memeber.php"
(?!.*context)               # negative look ahead for "context"
.*$                      # anything to the end
```

Comment: @Ruditabuti this will match url's containing `users` too

Comment: More precisely, it will match merely similar names like `xyzuser` and `membership`, and it isn't required to match the `.php` extension.

Comment: here, for the nitpickers `^(?=.*\/(?:user|member)\b\.php)(?!.*context).*$`

Comment: Your original answer probably worked because the OP didn't happen to use it on strings that contained `user` or `member` that weren't part of the file name (`user.php` or `member.php`) immediately after the domain.  The same vulnerability still exists for `context`.  Judging by the examples, you probably should be looking for `(?!.*[&?]context=)`, and you only need to look for it *after* the file name.  But your revised answer matches the question, so I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) to do this.

```
^(?!.*context).*\b(?:user|member)\.php.*$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX9rP0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*?(?:\buser\b|\bmember\b)\.php)(?:https?:\/\/)?[^/]*/(?:(?!context).)*$
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/14